# PHP define function didnot work in include file

Tags: php, include, constants

Let say I have 3 PHP files.

file1.php

```
<?php
    define('INTRO','Hello world');
?>
```

file2.php

```
<?php
    include('file1.php');
    echo 'My first text is = ' . INTRO;
?>
```

file3.php

```
<?php
    include('file2.php');
    echo 'My Second text is = ' . INTRO;
?>
```

When I run file `file2.php`, the text displayed is 'My first text is = Hello world', which is ok.

But the problem is when I run file3.php text displayed is

```
My first text is = INTRO
My Second text is = INTRO
```

it should display as

```
My first text is = Hello world
My Second text is = Hello world
```

It is because the constant value from `file1.php` didn't pass to file3.php

It worked fine on my pc, but not on the server.

Both my pc and server using Windows Server 2016 64bit + Apache2.4 64bit + Php5.6 64bit.

Am I missing something in server settings?

Comment: Sorry, works for me.

Comment: change you include to `require` and you may see that your file is not being included, include will fail silently.  My guess is you probably have a capitalization issue, linux filesystem is case sensitive windows is not.  So if `File1.php` is capital it will work on Windows and not on Linux, then the include just dies without telling you.  There is no problem with the code as it works locally, so that leaves only the environment.

Comment: But you should get _Notice: Use of undefined constant INTRO - assumed 'INTRO'_  use `error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');`

Comment: Not if error reporting is not on... its only a notice.  Which is why they get `INTRO` as a word, because it's not defined, and if it's not defined then the include is failing.  And if the include fails only on a server, it's a good bet it's capitalization, as I said.

Comment: same problem if i used require :)

Answer (score 1):

Change you `include` to `require` and you may see that your file is not being included, include will fail silently.

My guess is you probably have a capitalization issue, Linux filesystem is case sensitive windows is not. So if your include uses `file1.php` but your file is named `File1.php` with a capital it will work on Windows and not on Linux,

Then the include just dies without telling you. There is no problem with the code as it works locally, so that leaves only the environment.

Also it may be helpful to turn on error reporting in the first file you call put

```
<?php
 error_reporting(E_ALL);
 ini_set('display_errors', '1');
```

You should get a notice for undefined constant, which then php defaults to using the name of the constant for it's value ("INTRO").

This is why you get the text `INTRO`, which means that your constant is not defined. The only way I can see that happen is if the file is not included.  And if it works locally and not on a server, it's a good bet it's casing issue.

I am assuming you use Windows locally and Linux on your server, but as that is common it's not a big leap of logic to figure that out.

As a side note the file with the `define` in it should be `require_once` because if you include that file 2x you will get an error for an already defined constant.  If you cant do that, then you could do this

```
if(!defined("INTRO")) define('INTRO','Hello world');
```

Which checks if it's defined before defining it, but it's preferable to just use `require_once`

Also semantically, if a file being included is required (ie your program breaks without it) then it should be included using `require`.

Cheers.